# Odoo 10 : Extending existing module to show new menu item

Tags: python, xml, menu, odoo

I create a new module called employee_devies to add a new menu item in Employees (hr) module.

My manifest.py :

```
'depends': ['base','hr'],
```

and views.xml :

```
<odoo>
  <data>
<menuitem id="menu_test" parent="hr.menu_hr_root" name="Test" sequence="1"/>
 </data>
</odoo>
```

However,this new menu doesnt appear in Employees(hr) module.I also dont get any error as well. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Your menu must have a action only then it will be displayed on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your menu item `menu_test` is a folder menu. That means it will only became visible if it has some childs action menus. You could change your menu into an action menu just by providing the attribute `action` in the `menuitem` definition or add another menu with a `parent` attribute with the value of `menu_test` and an attribute `action` set in place(this last option could be at any level of a hierarchy of parent/childs menus, not need to be in the first child level). Both solutions will make it visible

Answer (score 2):

Please Provide action to the menu

```
 <odoo>
      <data>
    <menuitem id="menu_test" action="Your Action Here" parent="hr.menu_hr_root" name="Test" sequence="1"/>
     </data>
    </odoo>
```